# Mapping Spring form element to @ManyToOne element in Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am developing Employee Management application using Spring-Hibernate. I have two entities `Employee` and `Department`. And `Employee` entity has a field `Department` which is mapped to `Department` entity as @ManyToOne.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "dept")
private Department dept;
```

And accordingly @OneToMany mapping in `Department` entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dept")
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

My JSP Spring form is mapped to `Employee` entity. And it has a `form:select` element to select department with values as department ids.

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="createEmployee"
            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createdemployee"
            method="post">
 ..............
 ..............

<form:input path="employee.firstName" type="text" width="20px;" />
<form:select>
  <form:option value="1001">IT</form:option>
  <form:option value="1002">Finance</form:option>
  <form:option value="1003">Marketing</form:option>
  <form:option value="1004">Sales</form:option>
  <form:option value="1005">H.R</form:option>
</form:select>
```

How can I set `Deparment` object in `Employee` entity as per selection made on the form?

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/createdemployee")
public String goCreatedEmployee(Model model, Employee employee){
    employeeDataServices.addEmployee(employee);
    return "created_employee";
}
```

Comment: Why haven't you set the path attribute for the <form:select>  ?

Comment: @KarthikR I am not sure how to set it for `Department`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like :

```
<form:select path="employee.department.code">
  <form:option value="1001">IT</form:option>
  <form:option value="1002">Finance</form:option>
  <form:option value="1003">Marketing</form:option>
  <form:option value="1004">Sales</form:option>
  <form:option value="1005">H.R</form:option>
</form:select>
```

And from the Controller, get the employee model and get department's name?

Also add the request method in your code - POST/PUT.

```
@RequestMapping(value = /createdemployee, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String goCreatedEmployee(Model model, Employee employee){
    employeeDataServices.addEmployee(employee);
    return "created_employee";
}
```

Let me know if it works?